# Is amount returned to our return url by paypal?

Tags: paypal

Is amount returned by paypal to our return url ? Im trying to setup a return url for paypal to post their return parameters.May I know if amount is also returned by them?

Comment: What does their API say? What have you tried? Could you give some examples?

Answer (score 0):

On your return URL script you can call [GetExpressCheckoutDetails](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetExpressCheckoutDetails_API_Operation_NVP/) to obtain the amount (PAYMENTREQUEST_n_AMT) which you would need to do anyway to get your TOKEN (unless you've set useraction=commit on your redirect URL to PayPal.)